# Skim coating textured walls

Tags: drywall, walls, mudding, drywall-mud

We have plaster textured walls through out our entire house that are in good condition, but are just ugly.  Is it ok to skim coat or is drywall a better solution.  We are first timers doing our own home improvement so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If you shine a light down the length of the wall, casting a shadow, and ignoring the texture itself - is the wall relatively flat, or does it have a lot of bulges and waves, underneath the texture?

Comment: Also, can you provide more detail about the texture, maybe even add a picture?

Answer (score 3):

I've done this on one room- taking a knock-down texture and skim coating it to make it smooth.

The downside is that you then are able to see every wave, bump, and bobble that the drywall installers didn't bother fixing because they knew it would be hidden by texture. ;)

[image: Here's an in-progress pic]

[image]

I was able to get by with one coat and one sanding, but I was also applying a textured paint, so I might have had to do a second coat, otherwise.

Comment: Those waves, bumps, and bobbles - are a part of the very process used to apply a knock-down texture, and have nothing to do with the installers attention to detail.

Comment: Well, no, that's not quite what I meant- one stud being crooked and therefore pushed out (or in) compared to the neighboring studs-- virtually invisible with a texture, but visible once skim coated.